# Is a CHECK constraint checking if a column value is "IN" one of several other tables allowed?

Tags: sql

I'm taking a course in databases and we're only using sqlite3. We're asked to write a constraint in a `CREATE TABLE` statement that sqlite3 doesn't seem to support. Here's what I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE Product 
(
    maker varchar(1),
    model varchar(4),
    type varchar(10),
    CHECK (model IN (SELECT model FROM PC) OR 
           model IN (SELECT model FROM Laptop) OR
           model IN (SELECT model FROM Printer)) 
);
```

I'm wondering if this statement is legal in something like MySQL and whether it actually does what I want it do. I have three tables; PC, Laptop and Printer and I want for the model attribute of the table Product to have a corresponding model number in any of those three tables.

OK downvote me for an honest question... Thanks for the people who pointed me in the direction of sql fiddle online.

Comment: Why don't you just try? It's a one second question.

Comment: You can try some things out on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com). FWIW For MySQL the CHECK clauses are accepted but ignored.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yeah it's a stupid situation I'm in. I don't have MYSQL just sqlite3 and I'm supposed to turn this in within the hour:P.

Comment: "In something like MySQL" to make the question even broader.

Comment: @MikeW Brilliant! I'll give that a go

Comment: @GolezTrol Yeah I just know that partial queries aren't accepted in sqlite3 and I thought maybe they were in MYSQL or something like it, hence the phrasing of the question

Comment: I'm *guessing* (I have to, we don't have your assignment) that you've understood the task incorrectly. I hardly doubt it is required you have to use a `CHECK` constraint. More than likely you're expected to create a `Model` table to normalize that concept, and use *foreign key* constraints to enforce integrity.

Comment: @Jeroen I think we're supposed to only use these types of constraints as we're learning them right now. It's specifically stated that we can't use foreign keys and the material we're going through is these types of constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create table `Models` with fileds `model_id`, `type` (printer, laptop, etc...), maker, so on.
Don't make 3 different tables for PC, Laptop and Printers.

Sqlite also supports **foreign keys**. You should read more about them.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the tip, the assignment has artificial constraints so I can't use foreign keys, but this is very useful information for how to do it in the real world so I'm just gonna accept this answer.